# Apache Spark - Optimization and utilization of a CUDA GPU locally

Tags: java, optimization, apache-spark, cuda

I'm currently developing for Spark in JAVA, and before publishing to our Amazon cluster, I'm testing my code locally with Spark.  My question would be if there's any solution to utilize my GPU? Currently I can assign multiple cores of my CPU via `sparkConf.setMaster("local[4]");`, or set more of my RAM aside to the executor and driver with `sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "8g");` or the `--driver-memory 4g` switch. But apparently using a GPU for computing tasks is super effective. Is there a way I can make my locally run Spark use my GPU? CUDA seems to be the buzzword, but I couldn't find anything on how to set it up for Spark.

Also, what would be the optimal setup for RAM distribution? I have 16GBs available, how much should I allocate to the driver and how much to the execution?

Do you have any more tips on optimizing a local Spark?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many projects in the works that focus on taking advantage of GPGPU programming for Spark applications. Most of them actually work with AMD Aparapi or OpenCL as that provides more portability (since CUDA is only for NVidia GPUs).

Take a look at these two projects which allow you to run Spark applications on both conventional cores (CPU) and non conventional cores (GPUs, FPGAs):

1.0 [SparkCL](https://gitlab.com/mora/spark-ucores): I've used this in a project recently and wrote a report on it which you can find [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301359452_A_Performance_Investigation_of_SparckCL).

2.0 [HeteroSpark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpQxWcmXKyU): Fairly new and promising.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Do you know anything about the optimal RAM distribution? I wonder if the driver or the executor needs more.

Comment: Also, is there a way I can get SparkCL running under Windows? If I just get Git on Windows, clone the stuff as instructed and start running (with the directories changed), will it run?

Comment: SparkCL has a video tutorial which they perform on a Windows machine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na6GeOttZhA&index=5&list=PLOJY6HSc6DWnpPSmLKmr4GzkRv11QjdXw .  I used OSx and Ubuntu. The instructions work quite well too.

Answer (score 0):

Spark alone cannot use GPU. You can use libraries which can perform operations on GPU (GPU enabled linear algebra tools) on Spark but it doesn't concern core Spark and you need an use case that can benefit from this type of acceleration. GPU have large cost of loading data and low performance in general computing tasks.

Comment: Thank you! So what's with all the buzz about "GPGPU is the future of computing"? Or what kinds of tasks are GPUs better with?

Comment: There are powerful but it is not general processing tool. It is like FPGA give you many times more bang for the buck than CPU but it is not universal. If task is similar to rendering (many small tasks with sync) it is good candidate for GPU.